# How to retrigger a Jenkins build after failure using declarative syntax?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I am using declarative pipeline syntax. I want to re trigger my build for 3 times if it fails. I want to add this step in my pipeline may be in post step:
Something like below:

```
post { 
    failure{ 
        retrigger //try for 3 times atleast
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try [retry](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) (conditions:true)?
I can think of plenty of reasons why Jenkins might not want to support unlimited retries!

Answer (score 9):

The other answer is incorrect.  There is indeed a builtin to retry arbitrary sections of your job called [`retry`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times).

If you want to retry the whole job three times, you can wrap your entire job in a `retry` block:

```
retry(count: 3) {
  // your job definition here
}
```

However, if it's safe to do so, I would recommend wrapping individual steps or stages instead:

```
stage('my first stage') {
  retry(count: 3) {
    sh('some-command')
    sh('some-other-command')
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks jayhendren, this is what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Comment: @RonBob perhaps you could accept the answer

Comment: When I put a `retry` at the top of a `stage` block I get "Unknown stage section "retry"." error when validating.

Answer (score 3):

There is a retry parameter in the [global options](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options) when using declarative pipeline :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        retry(3)
    }
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be a built in pipeline step to do this, and neither does there seem to be a existing plugin that works with pipelines. I'd recommend having a look at the stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46852240/1019835

You can implement that code as a shared library, which would allow you to share your solution between projects. Have a look at this tutorial to do that: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate. What if I just want to retrigger the job upon build failure in post step. No matter how much number of time?