# Re-running a pipeline job if failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I've heard about the Naginator plugin, but unfortunately it's only for freestyle job type.

Is there any solution for pipeline jobs to be triggered if they failed? I thought about creating a command in the syntax or maybe triggering a freestyle job on the pipeline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrigger a Jenkins build after failure using declarative syntax?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5173/how-to-retrigger-a-jenkins-build-after-failure-using-declarative-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would probably be to add a `retry` option to the pipeline.

See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options

Comment: As @Bruce Becker mentioned, you can use `retry` steps in your jenkinsfile. optionally you can set how many time the stage tries attempting or set `timeout` See, https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#timeouts-retries-and-more